# Spliting list items into csv columns

Tags: python, split, export-to-csv

I'm trying to make a transmittal application which will take file names and turn them into a csv record of documents issued. Currently the python calls for all the file names in a given folder, creates a list, and splits the file name into document number, revision and title.

Currently I have been able to get the python to scrape the file names, create a list of this information and then split them to create a new list of separate data, i.e. *documentnumber,revision,title.pdf* to *[document number, Revision , Title].*

```py
    def getFiles():

    i = 0
    path = input("Paste in path for outgoing folder: ")
    numTitleRev = os.listdir(path)
    issueRec = []
    fileData = []
    totalList = len(numTitleRev)
    listNumber = str(totalList)
    print('\n' + "The total amount of documents in this folder is: " + listNumber + '\n')

    csvOutput = []

    while i < totalList:
        for item in numTitleRev:
            fileSplit = item.split(',', 2)
            fileTitle = fileSplit.pop(2)
            fileRev = fileSplit.pop(1)
            fileNum = fileSplit.pop(0)

        csvOutput.append([fileNum,fileRev,fileTitle])


        with open('output.csv', 'a') as writeCSV:
            writer = csv.writer(writeCSV)
            for row in csvOutput:
                writer.writerow(row)

        i += 1

    writeCSV.close()

    print("Writing complete")
```

```
The output I'm looking for is like so:
Number - Revision - Title
File1  - 01       - Title 1
File2  - 03       - Title 2 etc.
```

The code above is the process of spliting the list and it's records by ',' which is how the file names are stored in the folder.

The issue I think I have with the code below is that csvOutput is only sending the one result to the CSV, the last result of the string.

Then this is being printed in the csv for the total number of files in the folder, rather than split list record one, send to csv repeat with record two.

The problem is I can't think of how I would store this information as variables when the total amount of files is not constant.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what u want to do. The CSV to prints record is new for each execution ?

Comment: Your example is not testable/reproducible. What are `totalList` nad `numTitleRev`? Where do they come from? I assume that `totalList` is a list containing the file names? But what about the other?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to follow the information on the post a question not to add the entire code. I will update the original question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. This makes it a lot clearer. Indeed not pasting the entire code is a good recommendation. But your extracted code should still contain everything needed to understand the code. Even better if it is runnable. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a very good guide.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the nested `while/for` loop. I restructured the code a bit to make it testable locally (and runnable by just copy/pasting). That should also give you an idea of how to structure code to make it easier to ask for help.

I added a lot of comments explaining the changes I made.

```
import csv

# This part has ben extracted from the main logic, to make the code runnable
# with sample data (see main() below)
def getFiles():
    path = input("Paste in path for outgoing folder: ")
    numTitleRev = os.listdir(path)
    print("\nThe total amount of documents in this folder is: %s\n" % len(numTitleRev))
    return numTitleRev


# This piece of logic contained the core error. The nested "while" loop was
# unnecessary. Additionally, the ".append" call wass on the wrong indent-level.
# Removing the unnecessary while-loop makes this much clearer
def process_files(filenames):
    parsed = []
    for item in filenames:
        # Using "pop()" is a destructive operation (it modifies the list
        # in-place which may leed to bugs). In this case it's absolutely fine,
        # but I replaced it with a different syntax which in turn also makes
        # the code a bit nicer to read.
        fileNum, fileRev, fileTitle = item.split(',', 2)
        parsed.append([fileNum,fileRev,fileTitle])
    return parsed


# Similarly to "getFiles", I extracted this to make testing easier. Both
# "getFiles" and "write_output" are functions with "side-effects" which rely on
# external resources (the disk in this case). Extracting the main logic into
# "process_files" makes that function easily testable without the need of
# having the files really exist on the disk.
def write_output(parsed_data):
    with open('output.csv', 'a') as writeCSV:
        writer = csv.writer(writeCSV)
        for row in parsed_data:
            writer.writerow(row)
    print("Writing complete")


# This is just a simple main function to illustrate how the new functions are
# called.
def main():
    filenames = [  # <-- Some example data to make the SO answer runnable
        '0,1,this is an example.txt',
        '1,4,this is an example.txt',
        '2,200,this is an example, with a comma in the name.txt',
        '3,1,this is an example.txt',
    ]
    # filenames = getFiles()  <-- This needs to be enabled for the real code
    converted = process_files(filenames)
    write_output(converted)

# This special block prevents "import side-effects" when this Python file would
# be imported somewhere else.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To answer your question about ```totalList``` and ```numRevTitle```. ```numRevTitle``` creates a list from the file names from ```os.listdir(path)``` then ```totalList``` counts the number of records in ```numRevTitle``` so that the csv loops through and prints the correct amount of rows as is files in the folder.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked exactly as I wanted, also has given me a load of things to read up on.

Comment: One microscopic tidbit that I did not mention: When documenting function in Python, one should use "[docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)". But in this case I decided to use normal comments as they don't explain *what* is happening in that function but rather *how* it was implemented and *why* (which is no information that should be extracted into the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `csvOutput  = []` before loop and update it with each iteration `csvOutput.append([fileNum,fileRev,fileTitle])` This should solve the issue that only last iteration data is stored.

I assume this is a loop to iterate over your data `while i < totalList:` but you don't use the `i` counter to extract proper data chunk, instead you perform inner loop on the same data over and over.

If you have non-constant data you can just iterate over it like in your inner loop  but it is just a guess, you need to provide exact data structure and what problem you have with it for better answer.